# Does $n^\varepsilon \gt n\log n$ for $\varepsilon \gt 1$?

Tags: functions, logarithms

Does $n^\varepsilon \gt n\log n$ for $\varepsilon \gt 1$?

I'm pretty sure I heard once the lecturer stating this, is that true?

Comment: For any $n$ large enough and $\varepsilon>1$, $$\varepsilon\log(n) > \log(n)+\log\log(n),$$ so...

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent  to $n^{\varepsilon -1}>\log n$. Now, it's a basic result that 
$$\log n=o(n^{\alpha})\quad\text{for all}\enspace\alpha>0.$$
So it's true *if $n$ is large enough*.

Comment: I see, thank you Bernard